# Can I make wikipedia automatically correct my query when using api?

Tags: php, wikipedia-api, wikimedia

Consider the following [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=Andriyivski+Uzviz+Kyiv+Ukraine&title=Special:Search&go=Go&searchToken=197caiadljiz21hl1i91307tz). It says:

> Showing results for andriyivs'kyi uzviz kyiv ukraine. Search instead for Andriyivski Uzviz Kyiv Ukraine.

But when I do the following [request](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=search&gsrsearch=Andriyivski+Uzviz+Kyiv+Ukraine&gsrlimit=1&redirects=1&prop=extracts%7Cinfo%7Cpageprops%7Ccoordinates&exintro=1&explaintext=1&inprop=url&ppprop=disambiguation&coprop=type%7Cname%7Cdim%7Ccountry%7Cregion%7Cglobe&format=jsonfm), nothing of the sort happens. Is this possible using Wikipedia API?

Comment: It because the right link to display a result is: `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Search&search=andriyivs%27kyi+uzviz+kyiv+ukraine&fulltext=Search&profile=default&searchToken=2wjyxzo1cecifnk596uz42yek` ...when you search based on the suggestion provided by Wikipedia `Andriyivski Uzviz Kyiv Ukraine` it browse to a blank page, because the page doesn't exist.....

Comment: Okay, I've fixed Wikipedia link. But still don't get your point. When I search as a user, I get some results. When using API I don't.

Comment: Additionaly, when I search for ["St. Michael's Cathedrale Kyiv Ukraine"](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=search&gsrsearch=St.+Michael%27s+Cathedrale+Kyiv+Ukraine&gsrlimit=1&redirects=1&prop=extracts%7Cinfo%7Cpageprops%7Ccoordinates&exintro=1&explaintext=1&inprop=url&ppprop=disambiguation&coprop=type%7Cname%7Cdim%7Ccountry%7Cregion%7Cglobe&format=jsonfm), I get page "Ukrainian Catholic Eparchy of Saint Vladimir the Great of Paris", so it has nothing to do with whether the page exists, am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search API normally returns that data, but it cannot return anything (other than a list of pages) when used as a generator. Compare [your query](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&format=json&prop=extracts%7Cinfo%7Cpageprops%7Ccoordinates&generator=search&redirects=1&exintro=1&explaintext=1&inprop=url&ppprop=disambiguation&coprop=type%7Cname%7Cdim%7Ccountry%7Cregion%7Cglobe&gsrsearch=Andriyivski+Uzviz+Kyiv+Ukraine&gsrlimit=1) with a simple [action=query&list=search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&format=json&list=search&srsearch=Andriyivski+Uzviz+Kyiv+Ukraine&srlimit=1).